# What is the time complexity of the following nested loop dependency?

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

```
count=0;
for(i=1;i<=n;i*=5)
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
      count++;
```

Based on what I have understood so far, the inner loop will increase in powers of 5 like I have described on the table below ie when i=1, j=1, when i=5, j=5 and so on.

---

i | 1 | 5 |25 |125 |

---

j | 1 | 5 |25 |125 |

---

This makes j increase as in 5^0, 5^1, 5^2, 5^3 and so on. Using Trick of Gauss, 1+2+3+4...+n = (n² + n)/2 = n²/2 + n/2, this gives a total number of iterations of 5^((n² + n)/2).

Does this make the total runtime O(log base(5) n)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll consider loops where the number of iterations of the inner loop is independent of the value of the outer loop's index

then we will try different cases of `n` to figure out the right pattern :

```
n = 5
```

outer : 1 5

inner :

`i = 1` : 1 times

`i = 5` : 5 times

1 + 5 = 6 times , `k = 2`

```
n = 25
```

outer : 1 5 25

inner :

`i = 1` : 1 times

`i = 5` : 5 times

`i = 25` : 25 times

1 + 5 + 25 = 31 times , `k = 3`

```
n = 125
```

outer : 1 5 25 125

inner :

1 + 5 + 25 + 125 = 156 times , `k = 4`

inner :

```
(1 + ... + n/5^2 + n/5^1 + n/5^0)

n(1/n + ... + 1/5^2 + 1/5^1 + 1/5^0)

n(1/5^k-1 + ... + 1/5^2 + 1/5^1 + 1/5^0)

O(n(1/5^k-1 + ... + 1/5^2 + 1/5^1 + 1/5^0))
```

= O(n)

finally you can see from the pattern that we calculate time complexity is **O(n)**.

link to time complexity solution proof with geometric series:
https://justpaste.it/15fhs

Comment: at your last code line it is good to see that the factor in parenthesis is a constant

Comment: Can you please explain to me how it becomes O(n) using the formula for geometric progression?

Comment: yes you can conclude from geometric progression the time complexity 
see the updated answer link.

Comment: this video very helpful to understand big O calculating:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13Qb0GUo4Oc

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly apply the formula `1 + 2 + … + n = n(n+1)/2` here. 
`5^0 + 5^1 + … + 5^m` and `5^(0 + 1 + … + m)` are two entirely different things.

The series `5^0 + 5^1 + … + 5^m` is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series). The formula to use should be

[image]

> Which means `5^0 + 5^1 + … 5^m = O(5^m)`. Also note that 5<sup>m</sup> = n.

Comment: that's wrong. you are ignoring logarithmic behavior.

Comment: @gartenkralle what do you mean?

Comment: sum should not run till (n-1). it should run till log(n). Because of that result is different.

Comment: @gartenkralle The image was copied from Wikipedia, I did write `5^m` everywhere else. Edit: Re-typeset the image to avoid confusion.

Comment: but you are not answering what is the complixity of the loop

Comment: @gartenkralle That should be sufficient information for OP to figure out the answer. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to sum 5^m from m=0 to log5(n) which is less than 2n. So runtime is in **O(n)**.

For example if n=125 then sum is 156 (< 2n).

For any n the sum is less than 2n.

Comment: you are right exactly same as the pattern I got when testing different cases of n at inner loop